# Plot of gradient over a surface

Tags: plotting, regions

I have the following region:

```
curve = BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, -.5}, {2, .5}, {1, 2}, {0, 
    1}, {-1, .5}}, SplineClosed -> True];
reg = Region@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@curve;
```

and the function (over that region):

```
f[x_,y_]=Sin[x y+2];
```

How do I generate a 3D plot of the surface given by $(x,y,f(x,y))$ with a grid of unitary normal vectors, only on the region `reg`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
curve = BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, -.5}, {2, .5}, {1, 2}, {0, 
     1}, {-1, .5}}, SplineClosed -> True];

bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[curve];

f[x_, y_] = Sin[x y + 2];

p3d = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ bdg, 
  Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]]
```

[image]

You can post-process `p3d` to add

**1.** normal lines at the center of each polygon:

```
Normal[p3d] /. p : Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :>
   {p, Black, Line[{Mean[c], Mean[c] + Mean[vn]/3}]}
```

[image]

**2.** normal lines at polygon vertices:

```
Normal[p3d] /. p : Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :> 
  {p, Black, MapThread[Line[{##}] &, {c, c + vn/3}]}
```

[image]

To compare the two methods use an input plot produced with `MaxRecursion -> 0` and a small value for `PlotPoints`:

```
p3dB = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ bdg, Mesh -> None, 
   BoxRatios -> 1, PlotPoints -> 1, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[{Gray, Thin}], 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]];

Row[Show[#, ImageSize -> 400] & /@ 
  {Normal[p3dB] /. p : Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :> 
    {p, Black, Line[{Mean[c], Mean[c] + Mean[vn]/3}]},
   Normal[p3dB] /. p : Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :> 
    {p, Black, MapThread[Line[{##}] &, {c, c + vn/3}]}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the function `normalsShow` from [VertexNormals >> Applications](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexNormals.html):

```
normalsShow[g_Graphics3D] :=  Module[{pl, vl, n},
   {pl, vl} = First@Cases[g, GraphicsComplex[pl_, prims_, VertexNormals -> vl_, 
        opts___?OptionQ] :> {pl, vl}, Infinity];
   n = Length[pl];
   Show[g, 
    Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex @@ {Join[pl, pl + vl/3], 
      {Black, Line[Table[{i, i + n}, {i, n}]]}}]]
   ];


normalsShow @ p3d
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, however when adding in the option `ColorFunction -> "FallColors"` in the `p3d` definition the normal vectors won't show up, do you know  how to deal with this?

Comment: @Leonardo, try replacing `Polygon[c_, VertexNormals -> vn_]` with `Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___]`?

Comment: Solved, perfect.

Comment: @kglr I just asked a related question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246462/calculate-surface-normals-for-a-graphics3d-object. Could you please tell me how to get a list of the normal vectors only along the boundary? And plot them as well (along with the surface).