# Calculate surface normals at the boundary of a Graphics3D object

Tags: graphics3d, differential-geometry, discretization

How do I go about calculating and plotting the surface normals at the boundary of a `Graphics3D` object?

For example, consider this custom-defined `ParametricPlot3D` with boundaries (see [Get Graphics3D object for only part of a cone](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239746/get-graphics3d-object-for-only-part-of-a-cone)):

```
boundedOpenCone[centre_, tip_, Rc_, vec1_, vec2_, sign_] := 
 Module[{v1, v2, v3, e1, e2, e3},
  (* function to make 3d parametric plot of the section of a cone \
bounded between two vectors: tvec1 and tvec2*)
  
  {v1, v2, v3} = # & /@ HodgeDual[centre - tip];
  e1 = Normalize[v1];
  e3 = Normalize[centre - tip];
  e2 = Cross[e1, e3];
  
  ParametricPlot3D[
   s*tip + (1 - s)*(centre + Rc*(Cos[t]*e1 + Sin[t]*e2)), {t, 0, 
    2 \[Pi]}, {s, 0, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     RegionMember[
      HalfSpace[sign*Cross[vec1 - tip, vec2 - tip], tip], {x, y, z}]],
   PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][1]]
  ]

vec1 = {1, 0, 0}; vec2 = (1/Sqrt[2])*{1, 1, 0};
coneTip = {0, 0, 3};
cvec = {0, 0, 0};
Rc = Norm[vec1 - cvec];

boundedOpenCone[cvec, coneTip, Rc, vec1, vec2, -1];
```

[image]

Some great code for finding the normals everywhere on the surface can be found here: [Plot of gradient over a surface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219943/1871)

But I would like to get a list of the surface normal vectors, and plot them, *only along the boundary* of the domain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Definitions of `o`, `tvec1`, `tvec2` are missing.

Comment: Just corrected it.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219943/1871

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, that is perfect for getting the normals. Now I just need to figure out how to plot get the list of the normal vectors only along the boundary? And to plot them as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130226/polygon-mesh-compute-vertex-normals-for-smooth-shading

Comment: I just edited the question and made it more specific, so that it is now distinct from the cited pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, we need 2 more options in `boundedOpenCone`. The option `BoundaryStyle -> Automatic` creates a `Line` on the boundary so we can easily locate the coordinates of point on the boundary. `PlotPoints -> 100` isn't actually necessary, but will make the resulting boundary smoother.

```
boundedOpenCone[centre_, tip_, Rc_, vec1_, vec2_, sign_] := 
 Module[{v1, v2, v3, e1, e2, 
   e3},(*function to make 3d parametric plot of the section of a cone bounded between \
two vectors:tvec1 and tvec2*){v1, v2, v3} = # & /@ HodgeDual[centre - tip];
  e1 = Normalize[v1];
  e3 = Normalize[centre - tip];
  e2 = Cross[e1, e3];
  ParametricPlot3D[
   s*tip + (1 - s)*(centre + Rc*(Cos[t]*e1 + Sin[t]*e2)), {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {s, 0, 1}, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Automatic, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     RegionMember[HalfSpace[sign*Cross[vec1 - tip, vec2 - tip], tip], {x, y, z}]], 
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][1]]]

vec1 = {1, 0, 0}; vec2 = (1/Sqrt[2])*{1, 1, 0};
coneTip = {0, 0, 3};
cvec = {0, 0, 0};
Rc = Norm[vec1 - cvec];

pplot = boundedOpenCone[cvec, coneTip, Rc, vec1, vec2, -1];
```

Then we modify `normalsShow` from the document of `VertexNormals` a little to preserve only the normals on the boundary:

```
boundarynormals[g_Graphics3D] := 
  Module[{pl, vl, boundaryindexlst = Flatten@Cases[g, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity]}, 
    {pl, vl} = First@Cases[g, 
      GraphicsComplex[pl_, prims_, VertexNormals -> vl_, 
        opts___?OptionQ] :> {pl, vl}\[Transpose][[boundaryindexlst]]\[Transpose], 
      Infinity];
   Transpose@{pl, pl + vl/3}];

vectors = boundarynormals@pplot;

Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.01], Arrow@vectors}]~Show~pplot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And if I understand correctly, each element of `vectors` contains two 3-vectors, right? One each for the starting and ending point of the vector?

Comment: Is it possible to label the boundary points in the image above using `boundaryindexlst`? How would I do so?

Comment: @ap21 Your understanding for `vectors` is right. As to labeling, check document of `Callout`.

Comment: Another question please. In the reference you cited, and from which you got your base answer, there is another response for showing the normals at the vertices: ```Normal[g] /. 
 p : Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :> {p, Black, 
   MapThread[Line[{##}] &, {c, c + vn/3}]}```. How would you modify this to incorporate the boundary selection?

Comment: I ask because `boundarynormals[]` as defined doesn't work for a `Triangle[]`, while the `Normal[g]` definition works. Could you please make it work for a `Triangle[]`?

Comment: @ap21 How do you use the `Triangle`? `Normal@Graphics3D@Triangle[]/.   p : Polygon[c_, ___, VertexNormals -> vn_, ___] :> {p, Black,     MapThread[Line[{##}] &, {c, c + vn/3}]}` doesn't work as you desire, either.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. I hadn't cleared my variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
dg = DiscretizeGraphics[pplot];
```

Use the property `dg["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]["AdjacencyLists"]` to get edge-face connectivity and get indices of edges connected to a single face (these are the boundary edges of the surface).

```
boundaryedgeindices =  Flatten @ Position[
       Length /@ dg["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]["AdjacencyLists"], 1];

HighlightMesh[dg, Style[{1, boundaryedgeindices}, Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

Use the undocumented function `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` to get the normals:

```
boundaryedges = MeshPrimitives[dg, {1, boundaryedgeindices}];
boundaryedgenormals = Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[dg, {1, boundaryedgeindices}];
```

Show boundary edges and their normals:

```
boundaryEdgesAndNormals = Graphics3D[MapThread[
   {AbsoluteThickness[1], #, RandomColor[],Line[{Mean@#[[1]], Mean@#[[1]] + .2 #2}]} &,
   {boundaryedges, boundaryedgenormals}]]
```

[image]

Show together with the surface:

```
Show[pplot, boundaryEdgesAndNormals, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use *polygons* (instead of edges) at the boundary of the surface and their normals:

```
boundarypolygonindices = Flatten@
  Select[Length @ # == 1&]@dg["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]["AdjacencyLists"];

DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[
    MeshPrimitives[dg, {2, boundarypolygonindices}]], 
 PlotTheme -> "FaceNormals", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Note:** With this approach we can only get the direction of normals, since the vectors returned by `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals `` are normalized

```
MinMax[Norm /@ boundaryedgenormals]
```

> ```
>  {1., 1.}
> ```