# Drawing a beam of radius of the sphere

Tags: graphics3d

I'm still a newbie in Mathematica.
I want to draw a beam of radius of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without the surface appearing (look at the attached image). I would like so many to appear that the drawing looks dense but not so many that they overlap too much.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Please post some Mathematica code and some pictures to descript what you want.

Comment: I just added an image @cvgmt

Comment: Similar perhaps to [219943](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219943/plot-of-gradient-over-a-surface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to what Ulrich Neumann wrote:

```
With[{n = 1000, r = 0.01}, 
  Graphics3D[{MaterialShading["Copper"], 
              Cone[{#, {0, 0, 0}}, r] & /@ SpherePoints[n]}, 
             Background -> Black, Boxed -> False]]
```

To go further you'd need proper [ray tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)). For example, [export as POV](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/POV.html) and run through [POV-Ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POV-Ray).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try `SpherePoints[...]`

```
pts = SpherePoints[200];
Graphics3D [{Orange, Line[Map[{{0, 0, 0}, #} &, pts]]},Boxed -> False]
```

[image]